# Arduino with Ethernet Shield with PC to upload data to Microsoft Azure

Tags: arduino-mega, ethernet

i am a student doing a project related to datalogging. My project is a rehabilitation device that uses 2 rotary encoders to record data for rotation and linear movement of a human arm. The data extract is store inside the PC, but my supervisor wants me to upgrade it, he gave me an Arduino Ethernet Shield to attach it on Arduino Mega and he wants me to upload the data obtained from the device to Microsoft Azure database. I'm still new in both Arduino Ethernet Shield and Azure...can anyone help me?

What can i do with the Ethernet Shield? I mean we normally use the USB cable to work with Arduino, so this mean I have to connect both?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what Azure service? does it support non encrypted access

Comment: I'm still learning about Azure service, Azure has various features. 1 of the features is the database.

Comment: Assuming that you mean the SQL Database of Azure, a quick google search found me [this library](https://github.com/ChuckBell/MySQL_Connector_Arduino), which might work for you. You should start with the provided examples, as mostly they are a good starting point for a new library. There might be more to use out there. You just have to search for it. Try keywords involving sql / mysql combined with Arduino.

Comment: thank you very much, I will follow the example and try out.